# Not hitting last line in function call - javascript to validate form

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to validate a form using javascript.  For testing purposes, I'm just validating two input fields for the time being so I can test that it's working properly.  If a field is invalid (empty), it's successfully being added to the array, but when I try and alert the error(s), the function seems to return before the alert is ever being hit.  When I debug this, the next step over should go to my alert line, but rather the function returns.  Any ideas?

```
function validate() {
    var errors = ["test"];

    var text = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    if (isEmptyOrSpaces(text))
        errors.push("First name cannot be empty");

    text = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    if (isEmptyOrSpaces(text))
        errors.Push("Last name cannot be empty");

    alert("hello"); // this is the line that is never being hit.  Hello was just in 
                    // there as a test since it wasn 't working when trying to do 
    alert(errors.join("\n"));
}

function isEmptyOrSpaces(str) {
    return str === null || str.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
}
```

and here is some of the form

```
<form class="form-horizontal col-sm-8" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information:</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: it should be `errors.push` (lowercase `p`), not `errors.Push`. It's probably erroring out there. I'd check the inspector.

Comment: Wow, thanks you!  No idea how I missed that!

Comment: I have an idea how you missed that... You didn't look at your debug console. This is how you find problems *yourself*.